# How to use ansible-playbook --limit with an IP address, rather than a hostname?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Our inventory in INI style looks like this:

```
foo-host ansible_host=1.2.3.4 some_var=bla
bar-host ansible_host=5.6.7.8 some_var=blup
```

I can limit a playbook run to a single host by using the host alias:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml --limit foo-host
```

But I can't limit the run by mentioning the host's IP address from the `ansible_host` variable:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml --limit 1.2.3.4
ERROR! Specified hosts and/or --limit does not match any hosts
```

The reason I want to do that is because Ansible is triggered by an external system that only knows the IP address, but not the alias.

Is there a way to make this work? Mangling the IP address (e.g. `ip_1_2_3_4`) would be acceptable.

Things I've considered:

- Turn it on its head and identify all hosts by IP address:

  ```
  1.2.3.4 some_var=bla
  5.6.7.8 some_var=blup
  ```

  But now we can't use the nice host aliases anymore, and the inventory file is less readable too.
- Write a custom inventory script that is run after the regular inventory, and creates a group like `ip_1_2_3_4` containing only that single host, so we can use `--limit ip_1_2_3_4`. But there's no way to access previously loaded inventory from inventory scripts, so I don't know which groups to create.
- Create the new groups dynamically using the [`group_by` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/group_by_module.html). But because this is a task, it is run only after `--limit` has already decided that there are no hosts matching the pattern, and at that point Ansible just gives up and doesn't run the `group_by` task anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better solutions still welcome, but currently I'm doing it with a small inventory plugin, which (as opposed to an inventory script) *does* have access to previously added inventory:

**plugins/inventory/ip_based_groups.py**

```
import os.path
import re

from ansible.plugins.inventory import BaseInventoryPlugin
from ansible.inventory.group import Group


PATH_PLACEHOLDER = 'IP_BASED_GROUPS'
IP_RE = re.compile('^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$')


class InventoryModule(BaseInventoryPlugin):
    '''
    This inventory plugin does not create any hosts, but just adds groups based
    on IP addresses. For each host whose ansible_host looks like an IPv4
    address (e.g. 1.2.3.4), a corresponding group is created by prefixing the
    IP address with 'ip_' and replacing dots by underscores (e.g. ip_1_2_3_4).

    Use it by putting the literal string IP_BASED_GROUPS at the end of the list
    of inventory sources.
    '''

    NAME = 'ip_based_groups'

    def verify_file(self, path):
        return self._is_path_placeholder(path)

    def parse(self, inventory, loader, path, cache=True):
        if not self._is_path_placeholder(path):
            return
        for host_name, host in inventory.hosts.items():
            ansible_host = host.vars.get('ansible_host', '')
            if self._is_ip_address(ansible_host):
                group = 'ip_' + ansible_host.replace('.', '_')
                inventory.add_group(group)
                inventory.add_host(host_name, group)

    def _is_path_placeholder(self, path):
        return os.path.basename(path) == PATH_PLACEHOLDER

    def _is_ip_address(self, s):
        return bool(IP_RE.match(s))
```

**ansible.cfg**

```
[defaults]

# Load plugins from these directories.
inventory_plugins = plugins/inventory

# Directory that contains all inventory files, and placeholder to create
# IP-based groups.
inventory = inventory/,IP_BASED_GROUPS

[inventory]

# Enable our custom inventory plugin.
enable_plugins = ip_based_groups, host_list, script, auto, yaml, ini, toml
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *Playbook running a script running a playbook... it would work, but it's a bit hacky*

A: FWIW. It's possible to use json_query and avoid the script. For example

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_host: "{{ hostvars|dict2items|json_query(query)|first }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?value.ansible_host == '{{ my_host_ip }}' ].key"
      run_once: true
    - add_host:
        hostname: "{{ my_host }}"
        groups: my_group
      run_once: true

- hosts: my_group
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

> Q: "Unfortunately I'm running ansible-playbook from AWX, so no wrapper scripts allowed."

A: It is possible to run the script from the playbook. For example the playbook below

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_host: "{{ lookup('pipe', playbook_dir ~ '/script.sh ' ~ my_host_ip) }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
    - add_host:
        hostname: "{{ my_host }}"
        groups: my_group
      run_once: true

- hosts: my_group
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

gives

```
$ ansible-playbook -e 'my_host_ip=10.1.0.53' play.yml

PLAY [all] ********************

TASK [set_fact] ***************
ok: [test_01 -> localhost]

TASK [add_host] ***************
changed: [test_01]

PLAY [my_group] ***************

TASK [debug] ************
ok: [test_03] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "test_03"
}
```

(Fit the script to print the hostname only.)

> Q: *I can limit a playbook run to a single host by using the host alias:*

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml --limit foo-host
```

> *But I can't limit the run by mentioning the host's IP address from the ansible_host variable*

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml --limit 1.2.3.4
```

A: `ansible-inventory` and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) are able to resolve the host. For example the script

```
#!/bin/bash
my_host="$(ansible-inventory --list | jq '._meta.hostvars | to_entries[] | select (.value.ansible_host=="'"$1"'") | .key')"
my_host="$(echo $my_host | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')"
echo host: $my_host
ansible-playbook -l $my_host play.yml
```

with the inventory

```
test_01 ansible_host=10.1.0.51
test_02 ansible_host=10.1.0.52
test_03 ansible_host=10.1.0.53
```

and with the playbook.yml

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

gives

```
$ ./script.bash 10.1.0.53
host: test_03

PLAY [all] **********

TASK [debug] ************
ok: [test_03] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "test_03"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'm running `ansible-playbook` from AWX, so no wrapper scripts allowed :(

Comment: No problem. It's possible to run the script from a playbook.

Comment: Haha, yes, that is true :D A playbook running a script running a playbook... it would work, but it's a bit hacky, and it might be hard to plumb through all other variables like `--extra-vars`, `--vault-password-file`, `--user`, and who knows what else.

Comment: FWIW. It's possible to run it without the script.